# I am trying to make a hashmap of of string functions

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I am trying to make a map which stores a string as an identifier and a function that returns a string i have tried typedef but i kept running into problems because i couldn't convert my typedef string (command)() to a regular string i have also tried map commands but it gives me an expression expected error but it does work if i replace string with int. Does anybody know a way of doing this? This is what my code looks like

```
        #include "iostream"
        #include <map>
        #include <functional>


        using namespace std;

        class GameController {

        public:
            void inputReader();

        private:


            bool gameOver = false;
            map<string,string(*)()> commands;//Does not work

            //commands
            string  commandReader(string* inputCommand);
            void initCommands();

            //both
            char* end();
            string run();

            //while attacking
            string attack();
            string usePotion();
            string useItem();

            //while in room
            string engage();
            string searchRoom();
            string rest();
            string checkBag();
            string checkMap();
            string checkStats();
            //string save();



        };



        #endif //ROGUE_GAMECONTROLLER_H

    #include "GameController.h"

    GameController::GameController(){
        initCommands();
    }
void GameController::inputReader() {

while (!gameOver){
    string x;
    getline(cin,x);
    cout << commandReader(&x) << endl;
    }

}

string  GameController::commandReader(string *inputCommand) {

    for (map<string,string>::iterator it = commands.begin(); it!=commands.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(it->first == *inputCommand)
        {
            return it->second;
        }

    }
    return "Computer says no type help for commands";
}

    void GameController::initCommands() {


        commands["end"] = end;
        //while attacking
        commands["run"] = run;
        commands["attack"] = attack;
        commands["use potion"] = usePotion;
        commands["use item"] = useItem;

        //while in room
        commands["engage"] = engage;//TODO
        commands["search"] = searchRoom;
        commands["rest"] = rest;
        commands["check bag"] = checkBag;
        commands["map"] = checkMap;
        commands["stats"] = checkStats;
    }
```

Comment: Give this a read: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: `run` is not a function, it is a member function.  You have something that claims to be the address of a chicken, and you are writing down the address of a duck.  The C++ type system complains.

Comment: Here you go, I fixed a couple of other compile time issues. What's left are some linker errors, but that's because you didn't define any of the relevant member functions: http://ideone.com/ssTaQM

Comment: map<string,string (GameController::*)()> commands; IDE says: called object is not a function

Comment: `GameController::commandReader` should just call commands.find(), and let the container do the iterating itself (or hashing and indexing in the case of the unordered_map example I provided below). I also can discern no reason for the function to take a pointer to a string instead of a const reference to a string: `std::string GameController::commandReader(const std::string &inputCommand)`
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers to member functions is not like pointers to free functions or even static methods. For one thing all member functions have a hidden `this` pointer in the function parameters that makes all of this object magic work.

Going through step by step:

First, define a helper:

```
typedef string (GameController::*funcp)();
```

This defines type `funcp` which represents a pointer to a member function of `GameController` (to partly take care of the `this` problem) that takes no parameters and returns `string`

Then, modify your map to use `funcp`

```
map<string, funcp> commands;
```

Then you have to change the assignment of the member functions a bit to be brutally explicit that it is a pointer and a member of `GameController`

```
commands["end"] = &GameController::end;
```

You can also save yourself some runtime trouble and use an initializer list here rather than a function and a map in every single `GameController` object. That'll take a bit of extra explaining and I have to be on the move in a few minutes. Sorry about that. A static map with static initializing really is better and worth your time researching, though.

The next bit I stole from the [C++ Super FAQ](http://%20isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members). Read this link. Worth reading all of it, because it heads off a lot of the question you will have.

```
#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object,ptrToMember)  ((object).*(ptrToMember))
```

This makes calling the function awesomely easy.

```
return CALL_MEMBER_FN(*this, it->second)();
```

And that should about do it for you.

## edit:

Tweej demonstrates the generally better way to do this, std::function and std::bind, in their answer. Since I'm advocating the ancient ways, I'd like to explain why.

Two reasons: one is tunnel vision directly answering OP's question.

The second is With the ancient ways I could easily make `commands` static and save having to create a new copy of `commands` for every instance of `GameController`. When using std::bind, you have to have the bound object, and that ruins the static idea.

Poking around at the idea of just using std::function seems to have born fruit and rendered obsolete the ancient ways. gone is the CALL_MEMBER_FN macro. Gone is the funcp typedef

The map is now defined as static, what I was aiming for the the old-pre C++11 approach. Note the funcp typedef is replaced by a function that takes a pointer to GameController to supply `this`.

```
static map<string, std::function<string(GameController*)>> commands;
```

And the map is now rigged to use a static initializer list. No function required. This initializer needs to sit outside the class definition because... I'm not sure why. I think this is changed in C++14.

```
map<string, std::function<string(GameController*)>> GameController::commands
{
    {"end", &GameController::end},
    {"run", &GameController::run},
    {"attack", &GameController::attack},
    {"use potion", &GameController::usePotion},
    {"use item", &GameController::useItem},
    {"engage", &GameController::engage},
    {"search", &GameController::searchRoom},
    {"rest", &GameController::rest},
    {"check bag", &GameController::checkBag},
    {"map", &GameController::checkMap},
    {"stats", &GameController::checkStats}
};
```

The map is initialized once and  only once. All GameControllers will use the same `commands`, so the constructor is really dumb

```
GameController::GameController()
{
    // init function is gone
}
```

Command reader gets a big rip-up, mostly because the point of a map is you can search it by the key. So I search for the key rather than iterating. The function call is now obvious and dead simple:

```
string GameController::commandReader(const string &inputCommand)
{
    map<string, std::function<string(GameController*)>>::iterator found = commands.find(inputCommand);
    if (found != commands.end())
    {
        return found->second(this);
    }
    return "Computer says no type help for commands";
}
```

Comment: Thx this was what i was looking for!

Comment: @LúthienFelagund added on some supplemental information on an even better way to do this.

Comment: If the functions took a parameter, what would change about this?

Comment: @gnychis `typedef string (GameController::*funcp)(<parameters go here>);` or `std::function<string(GameController*, <other params go here>)`. [Docs for `std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Answer (score 2):

This question is tagged C++11, so here's a concise example which uses unordered_map (a real hash map, unlike std::map which my STL reference says is commonly implemented using binary search trees), and std::function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

std::string foo()
{
   return "foo!";
}

struct MyClass
{
   static std::string bar()
   { return "bar!"; }

   std::string FizzBuzz() const
   { return "FizzBuzz!"; }

   std::string operator()() const
   { return "Myclass!"; }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   MyClass mc;

   std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<std::string()>> commands;

   commands["myfoo"]   = foo;
   commands["mybar"]   = MyClass::bar;
   commands["myfb"]    = std::bind(&MyClass::FizzBuzz, mc);
   commands["myclass"] = mc;

   for( const auto &f : commands)
      std::cout << f.second() << std::endl;

   std::cout << commands["myfoo"]() << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```